# Anko doAsync not fired on first launch of application

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm loading some info in async this way:

```
    doAsync {
        val car = initCar()
        onComplete {
            Log.e("async", "fired")
            loadedCar = car
            loadCarView()
        }
    }
```

**loadedCar** variable is a simple **CarModel** and `initCar()` function returns already initialized CarModel.

```
private fun initCar(): Car {
    fromVoid = intent.extras == null || intent.extras!!.isEmpty || !intent.hasExtra("car_id")
    val car = Car()
    if (fromVoid) {
        car.name = ""
        car.model = ""
        dbManager.add(car)
        car.id = dbManager.latestInsertId
    } else {
        car.id = intent.getLongExtra("car_id", -1)
        car.name = intent.getStringExtra("car_name")
        car.model = intent.getStringExtra("car_model")
    }
    return car
}
```

and `loadCarView()` simply inits textViews and EditTexts...

Problem is that once application is installed and this activity opened, it does not fire **doAsync** function, but once i re-launch application, it does... I mean i'v tested multiple times and that's usually a case.

P.S also want to note that application was not originally written in kotlin and was converted, if it gives something...

Comment: please post your `Activity` code

Comment: Shouldn't the log of "async fired" be before the call to initCar()? Otherwise you are in danger of saying it didn't fire, when in fact it had fired but just hadn't completed (which is, I suspect, what is happening to you).

Comment: Exactly that's a problem, if there was excessive async task, i'd say i exactly same, just it's a very simple task that in fact does not require separate thread to work on, but now it has 3 value to insert in db, what if there is a excessive amount of text with html tags and bbcodes (comment)... it's kind of safe workaround to ensure that it does not hang ui... but i changed to dbFlow so, i think there won't be a need to use async task